# Behavior of delete operator in javascript

Tags: javascript

It seems in JavaScript you can’t `delete` function arguments but you 
can `delete` global variables from a function.

Why this behavior?

```
var y = 1;
(function (x) { return delete y; })(1); // true

(function (x) { return delete x; })(1); // false
```

Comment: Both return `false` in normal use (i.e. not within the Firebug or browser console, which use `eval()`). See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** Both return `false` in normal use (i.e. not within the Firebug or browser console, which use `eval()`). See [Tim Down’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009115/behavior-of-delete-operator-in-javascript/7010015#7010015) (it should be the accepted one).

Comment: Actually the first example doesn't work because `y` is declared using `var` and therefore has the `[[DontDelete]]` attribute (in ECMAScript 3: the equivalent attribute is `[[Configurable]]` is ECMAScript 5) set to true.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, neither should return `true`, and indeed they don't in Firefox or Chrome (untested in other browsers). I imagine you tested this with Firebug or another browser console, which [changes things due to the console using `eval()`](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#firebug_confusion). `delete` only deletes properties of an object and cannot normally delete a variable declared using `var`, whatever the scope.

Here's an excellent article by Kangax on the subject: http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/