# Able to delete non-var variables, but not var declared variables?

Tags: javascript, variables

For example: Here I declare a variable with var, then try to delete it and fail.

```
var derp = "foo";        
\> "foo"    
derp;    
\> "foo"    
this.derp;    
\> "foo"    
delete derp;    
\> false    
derp;    
\> "foo"
```

However, if I create a variable without var, then I am able to successfully delete it.

```
perd = "boo";    
\> "boo"    
this.perd;    
\> "boo"    
delete perd;    
\> true    
perd;    
\> undefined
```

Can anyone explain this behavior for me? I'm sure there is some reason.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Behavior of delete operator in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009115/behavior-of-delete-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `delete` operator does not delete variables. It only removes properties from objects.

When you use a bare identifier without declaring it with the `var` keyword, it is not a variable, but rather a property of the global variable (usually `window` in a browser). That's why you can delete it.

More information about the `delete` operator than you probably want to know is available [here](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/).

Comment: Note that you can still access (but not delete) a variable with `globalObject.varName` when it's declared with `var` on the global scope (like in `this.derp` in the OP).

Comment: Thank you for the concise answer Ted, and the link looks great, I'll check it out!

Comment: @bfavaretto - Absolutely correct. The link at the end of my answer explains why this is so. (It also why my answer is not 100% technically correct. Even `var x` variables are properties; they just happen to be marked as undeletable and, when not at global scope, properties of an inaccessible activation object. I just felt that a fully accurate explanation would be kind of hard to understand.)